# Reading contents of binary file into object vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am having trouble displaying *all* the contents of a vector that I've read contents of a binary file into. I can access individual elements of this vector but cannot print all of them. My code goes as follows:

```
BankSystem::BankSystem(string file_name) {
    vec_acc.reserve(10);
    fstream acc_file(file_name, ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        acc_file.seekg(sizeof(Account)*i);
        acc_file.read((char*)&vec_acc[i], sizeof(Account));
    }
    acc_file.close();
}
```

So this constructor is suppose to read the contents of the binary file into an `Account` vector.

I know that the data has been correctly read into the `Account` vector because I can perform method functions like `getName` or `getBalance` on them. However when I try to display the contents of the vector:

```
void BankSystem::showAccounts() {
    std::copy(vec_acc.begin(), vec_acc.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Account>
    (cout, " "));
}
```

This had worked previously when I was pushing the `Account` objects into the vector. However, I cannot get it to work since I've added the ability to read the contents into the vector from the binary file.

Comment: What does `Account` contain?

Comment: Is Account a POD? Does following compile in your code: `static_assert(std::is_pod<Account>::value, "Account must be a POD.");`

Comment: @Galik I'm confused what you're asking exactly. It contains 7 method functions, 6 data members, and an overloaded `operator`. `ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Account& acc) { os << "Account(Name: " << acc.firstName + ' ' + acc.lastName << ", Account Number: " << acc.acc_num << ")"; return os }`

Comment: @marcinj no it did not compile `static assertion failed: Account must be a POD`

Comment: @quantik - so this is where your problem is comming from, if you want to read data from files directly to your Account type, then it may contain only primitive types, ie.: `struct Account { char firstName[32]; /* .... */ };`

Comment: So what data members does `Account` contain?

Comment: @Galik `string first_name` `string last_name` `int pin` `float balance` `float limit` and `long int acc_num`

Comment: Then its not a POD because of the `std::string`. So you can not serialize this way.

Answer (score 1):

You do `vec_acc.reserve(10);` but your `vec_acc.size()` is still 0 and your `vec_acc.begin() == vec_acc.end()`.

But even if you change it to `.resize(10)` you may have issues serializing objects of non-POD type this way.

Comment: I do not believe this is the source of the problem because when I was pushing `Account` objects into the `vec_acc` I use `reserve` and the code worked perfectly fine then. But yes that's why I did not use `resize` not really sure how to circumvent this issue.

Comment: When you push element into vector, vector size grows. When you access `vec_acc[i]` without resizing you have UB (that could be crash or worse).